# select max of sum sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum, max

i have a results from some tables like this with (700 rows)

```
country         province       purchase_power 
Angola          Cuanza Sul          10
Angola          Huambo              2
Angola          Namibe              2
Angola          Uige                12
Argentina       Buenos Aires        15
Argentina       Catamarca           3
Argentina       Corrientes          1
Argentina       Jujuy               13
Argentina       La Rioja            17
Argentina       Mendoza             1
Argentina       Misiones            1
Argentina       Neuquen             2
Argentina       San Juan            10
Argentina       San Luis            4
Argentina       Santa Cruz          1
```

i got this by using this query

```sql
select  c.name as country,p.name as province,sum(qty) as purchase_power
from province p,purchases,country c
where P.rowid = Purchases.province and qty>0 and c.code=p.country and product=0  
group by p.name
```

i want only the province with the highest purchace_power for every country

the performance should be considered

```
ex output 
country         province       purchase_power 
Angola          Uige                12
Argentina       La Rioja            17
```

Comment: `select * from t group by country having max(purchase_power);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notes:

- You must use explicit joins instead of implicit ones.
- Also you must add `c.name` to `group by`.
- Although SQLite allows columns not used in the `group by` clause to be selected, if you don't want surprises you must follow standard SQL.

Now, since performance is an issue, you can use a CTE for your query and execute it only once to use its results:

```
with cte as (
  select 
    c.name as country,
    p.name as province,
    sum(t.qty) as purchase_power
  from province p 
  inner join purchases t on p.rowid = t.province
  inner join country c on c.code = p.country 
  where t.qty > 0 and t.product=0  
  group by c.name, p.name
)
select cte.* from cte 
inner join (
  select country, max(purchase_power) purchase_power
  from cte
  group by country
) t on t.country = cte.country and t.purchase_power = cte.purchase_power
```

Comment: *same results*? what do you mean?

Comment: [22:22:56] SQLiteStudio was unable to extract metadata from the query. Results won't be editable.

Comment: and its gave the same redundant provinces like my previous query

Comment: i cant thank you enough it works now 100% correct , thank you very much .

Comment: i did some changes to the query and its now showing  c.name as country,
p.name as province,
sum(qty) as purchase_power,
count(*) as abs,
cast( sum(qty) as float)/ count(*) as prop             but i couldn't remove the sum sum(qty) as purchase_power, and i didn't find a way around that

Comment: *i couldn't remove the sum sum(qty) as purchase_power* why? If you don't want it just delete it.

Comment: its says [12:23:12] Error while executing SQL query on database 'g': no such column: purchase_power i couldn't solve this since i am new to sqlite

Comment: `purchase_power` is an alias for `sum(qty)`. It does not really exist in any table. You named that sum `purchase_power`.

Comment: when i remove it from the main select and replace the max(purchase_power) with max(sum(qty)) i have this error [20:58:53] Error while executing SQL query on database 'g': no such column: qty

Comment: You can't have double aggregation: max(sum(qty)). In one query you get sum(qty) and give it an alias like purchase_power and then you use this query to get max(purchase_power).